# When using Firebase Notification, Facebook kit makes VerifyError

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, fatal-error, firebase-notifications

I am using Facebook Kit for LogIn. It works fine but when I add firebase messaging into my app, it crashed when LogIn button clicked, Firebase Notification works fine. Can anyone give me the solution

Error Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: xyz.sheba.bondhu, PID: 20884

java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzasm because it failed compile-time verification (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zzasm' appears in /data/app/xyz.sheba.bondhu-2/base.apk:classes20.dex)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity.onCreate(AccountKitActivity.java:348)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5442)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

My Gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.github.stfalcon:smsverifycatcher:0.3.1'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
// Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
// JSON Parsing
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.2'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying various kinds of technique i can't solve this problem. Then i read all their(facebook, firebase, google map) documentations and find a solution.

In that case, when i was singly use `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'`, it works fine. But when i use both `compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'` it makes collusion because facebook kit 4.+ doesn't support firebase 11.0.4. it only support 11.0.1. That was the problem.

So that Use

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
```

and this will solve the problem.